# Trying to remove quadtree from javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, quadtree

I got an agar.io clone from online and I am trying to remove the Quadtree in the corner (acts as a map) completely! I try to delete everything associating with the quadtree but i end up with a gray screen. Could someone please remove the map from the top right corner for me or tell me which lines to remove?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="viewport">
        <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas3" width="250px" height="250px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var MouseHandler = (function() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var mouseIn = false;

    var init = function(eventSrc) {
        eventSrc.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        eventSrc.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);
        eventSrc.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver);
    };

    var onMouseOut  = function() {
        mouseIn = false;
    };

    var onMouseOver = function() {
        mouseIn = true;
    };

    var onMouseMove = function(e) {
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
    };

    var getPos = function() {
        return {
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
    };

    var isMouseIn = function() {
        return mouseIn;
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        getPos: getPos,
        isMouseIn: isMouseIn
    };
}());

Quadtree.MAX_OBJECTS = 5;
Quadtree.MAX_LEVEL = 5;
function Quadtree(lvl, bnds) {
    var level = lvl;
    var bounds = bnds;
    var objects = [];
    var nodes = [];

    var xMiddle = bounds.x + (bounds.width / 2);
    var yMiddle = bounds.y + (bounds.height / 2);

    var clear = function() {
        objects = [];
        nodes = [];
    };

    var split = function() {
        nodes[0] = new Quadtree(level+1, {x: xMiddle, y: bounds.y , width: bounds.width/2, height: bounds.height/2});
        nodes[1] = new Quadtree(level+1, {x: bounds.x, y: bounds.y, width: bounds.width/2, height: bounds.height/2});
        nodes[2] = new Quadtree(level+1, {x: bounds.x, y: yMiddle, width: bounds.width/2, height: bounds.height/2});
        nodes[3] = new Quadtree(level+1, {x: xMiddle, y: yMiddle, width: bounds.width/2, height: bounds.height/2});
    };

    var getIndex = function(rec) {
        var top = (rec.y > bounds.y && (rec.y+rec.height) < yMiddle);
        var bottom = (rec.y > yMiddle && (rec.y+rec.height) < (bounds.y+bounds.height));

        if(rec.x > bounds.x && (rec.x+rec.width) < xMiddle) {
            if(top) {
                return 1;
            } else if(bottom) {//LEFT
                return 2;
            }
        } else if(rec.x > xMiddle && (rec.x+rec.width) < (bounds.x+bounds.width)) {
            if(top) {
                return 0;
            } else if(bottom) {//RIGHT
                return 3;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };

    var insert = function(ent) {
        var rec = ent.getBounds();
        var index = getIndex(rec);
        var len = 0;
        var i = 0;

        if(nodes[0] && index !== -1) {
            nodes[index].insert(ent);
            return;
        }

        objects.push(ent);

        if(objects.length > Quadtree.MAX_OBJECTS && level < Quadtree.MAX_LEVEL) {
            if(!nodes[0]) {
                split();
            }

            len = objects.length;
            while(i < objects.length) {
                index = getIndex(objects[i].getBounds());

                if(index !== -1) {
                    nodes[index].insert(objects[i]);
                    objects.splice(i, 1);
                } else {
                    i += 1;
                }
            }

        }
    };

    var retrieve = function (list, ent) {
        var rec1 = bounds;
        var rec2 = ent.getBounds();

        if(rec2.x < (rec1.x+rec1.width)  && (rec2.x+rec2.width)  > rec1.x &&
           rec2.y < (rec1.y+rec1.height) && (rec2.y+rec2.height) > rec1.y) {

            for(var o in objects) {
                if(objects[o] !== ent) {
                    list.push(objects[o]);
                }
            }

            if(nodes.length) {
                nodes[0].retrieve(list, ent);
                nodes[1].retrieve(list, ent);
                nodes[2].retrieve(list, ent);
                nodes[3].retrieve(list, ent);
            }
        }

        return list;
    };

    var drawTree = function(ctx) {
        draw(ctx);
        if(nodes[0]) {
            nodes[0].drawTree(ctx);
            nodes[1].drawTree(ctx);
            nodes[2].drawTree(ctx);
            nodes[3].drawTree(ctx);
        }
    };

    var draw = function(ctx) {
        var entAttr = null
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeRect(bounds.x/20, bounds.y/20, bounds.width/20, bounds.height/20);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'gray';
        for(o in objects) {
            entAttr = objects[o].getAttr();
            ctx.fillRect(entAttr.x/20, entAttr.y/20, 3, 3);
        }
    };

    var toString = function() {
        return '('+bounds.x+','+bounds.y+')'+'['+bounds.width+','+bounds.height+']';
    };

    return {
        clear: clear,
        insert: insert,
        retrieve: retrieve,
        drawTree: drawTree,
        toString: toString,
    };
}

function Circle(attr) {
    attr = attr || {};

    var x = attr.x || 0;
    var y = attr.y || 0;
    var mass = attr.mass || 500;
    var color = attr.color || 'white';
    var borderColor = attr.borderColor || 'black';
    var velX = attr.velX || 0;
    var velY = attr.velY || 0;
    var droplet  = attr.droplet || false;

    var maxVel = 80 * (80 / Math.sqrt(mass));
    var radius = Math.sqrt( mass / Math.PI ); //1 unit of area === 1 uni of mass

    var getAttr = function() {
        return {
            x: x,
            y: y,
            mass: mass,
            radius: radius,
            color: color,
            velX: velX,
            velY: velY,
            maxVel: maxVel
        };
    };

    var setAttr = function(attr) {
        x = (attr.x !== undefined)? attr.x: x;
        y = (attr.y !== undefined)? attr.y: y;
        mass = (attr.mass !== undefined)? attr.mass: mass;
        color = (attr.color !== undefined)? attr.color: color;
        velX = (attr.velX !== undefined)? attr.velX: velX;
        velY = (attr.velY !== undefined)? attr.velY: velY;
    };

    var incMass = function(dMass) {
        mass += dMass;
        maxVel = 100 * (100 / Math.sqrt(mass));
        radius = Math.sqrt( mass / Math.PI );
    };

    var intersects = function(ent2) {
        var ent2Attr = ent2.getAttr();

        var dX = Math.abs(ent2Attr.x - x);
        var dY = Math.abs(ent2Attr.y - y);
        var totalRadius = ent2Attr.radius + radius;

        return (dX < totalRadius && dY < totalRadius);
    };

    var draw = function(ctx, cam) {
        var camSize = cam.getSize();
        var rPos = cam.getRelPos(getAttr());

        //if outside Cam view
        if((rPos.x + radius) <  0 || (rPos.y + radius) <  0 || (rPos.x - radius) >  camSize.width || (rPos.y - radius) > camSize.height) {
            return;
        }

        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.strokeStyle = borderColor;
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(rPos.x, rPos.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    };

    var update = !droplet && function(dTime) {
        x += velX * dTime;
        y += velY * dTime;
    };

    var getBounds = function() {
        return {
            x: x-radius,
            y: y-radius,
            width: radius*2,
            height: radius*2,
        };
    };

    return {
        getBounds: getBounds,
        getAttr: getAttr,
        setAttr: setAttr,
        incMass: incMass,
        intersects: intersects,
        draw: draw,
        update: update
    };
}

var gameManager = (function() {
    var canvasGrid = null;
    var canvasEnt = null;
    var canvasQuadtree = null;
    var ctxGrid = null;
    var ctxEnt = null;
    var ctxQuadTree = null;
    var dTime = 1 / 60;
    var player = null;
    var entityBag = [];
    var qTree = null;
    var drwQuad = 0;

    var addEntity = function(ent) {
        entityBag.push(ent);
    };

    var removeEntity = function(ent) {
        var len =  entityBag.length;
        var i = 0;

        for(i=0; i<len; i+=1) {
            if(ent === entityBag[i]) {
                entityBag.splice(i, 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    var init = function(cvsGridId, cvsEntId, cvsQuadtree) {
        canvasGrid = document.getElementById(cvsGridId);
        canvasEnt = document.getElementById(cvsEntId);
        canvasQuadtree = document.getElementById(cvsQuadtree);
        ctxGrid = canvasGrid.getContext('2d');
        ctxEnt = canvasEnt.getContext('2d');
        ctxQuadtree = canvasQuadtree.getContext('2d');

        fitToContainer(canvasGrid);
        fitToContainer(canvasEnt);

        ctxGrid.fillStyle = '#F0FBFF';
        ctxGrid.strokeStyle = '#BFBFBF';
        ctxGrid.lineWidth = 1;

        MouseHandler.init(document);

        qTree = new Quadtree(0, {x:0, y:0, width:5000, height:5000});

        player = new Circle({
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            color: 'red',
            mass: 1000,
            velX: 500,
            velY:500
        });

        Camera.init(ctxEnt, player);

        addEntity(player);
        gameloop();
    };

    var handleInput = function() {
        if(MouseHandler.isMouseIn() === false) {
            player.setAttr({ velX: 0, velY: 0 });
            return;
        }

        var pAttr = player.getAttr();
        var rPlyrPos = Camera.getRelPos(player.getAttr());
        var mPos = MouseHandler.getPos();
        var dX = mPos.x - rPlyrPos.x;
        var dY = mPos.y - rPlyrPos.y;

        var vLength = Math.sqrt( (dX*dX) + (dY*dY) );

        var normX = dX / vLength;
        var normY = dY / vLength;

        var newVelX = normX * (pAttr.maxVel * vLength / 50);
        var newVelY = normY * (pAttr.maxVel * vLength / 50);

        player.setAttr({
            velX: newVelX,
            velY: newVelY
        });
    };

    var drawGrid = function() {
        var camPos = Camera.getPos();
        var camSize = Camera.getSize();

        var start = Math.floor(camPos.x / 40);
        var relX = Camera.getRelPos({x: (start*40), y: 0}).x;

        var numLines = camSize.width / 40;
        var i = 0;


        ctxGrid.fillRect(0, 0, canvasGrid.width, canvasGrid.height);

        for(i=0; i<numLines; i+=1) {
            ctxGrid.beginPath();
            ctxGrid.moveTo(relX + (40 * i), 0);
            ctxGrid.lineTo(relX + (40 * i), camSize.height);
            ctxGrid.stroke();
        }

        start = Math.floor(camPos.y / 40);
        var relY = Camera.getRelPos({x: 0, y: (start * 40)}).y;
        numLines = camSize.height / 40;

        for(i=0; i<numLines; i+=1) {
            ctxGrid.beginPath();
            ctxGrid.moveTo(0, relY + (40 * i));
            ctxGrid.lineTo(camSize.width, relY + (40 * i));
            ctxGrid.stroke();
        }
    };

    var handleCollisions = function() {
        var possibleColl = [];
        var collisions = [];
        var coll = null;
        var ent = null;
        var plyMass = player.getAttr().mass
        var entMass = 0;

        qTree.clear();
        for(ent in entityBag) {
            qTree.insert(entityBag[ent]);
        }

        possibleColl = qTree.retrieve([], player);

        while(ent = possibleColl.pop()) {

            if(player.intersects(ent)) {
                entMass = ent.getAttr().mass;

                if(plyMass > (1.5 * entMass)) {
                    removeEntity(ent);
                    player.incMass(entMass);
                }
            }

            var entAttr = ent.getAttr();
            ctxQuadtree.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctxQuadtree.fillRect(entAttr.x/20, entAttr.y/20, 3, 3);
        }
    };

    var fitToContainer = function(canvas) {
        canvas.style.width='100%';
        canvas.style.height='100%';
        canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
    };

    var gameloop = function() {
        var len = entityBag.length;
        var i = 0;
        var ent = null;

        handleInput();
        Camera.update();

        drawGrid();

        if(drwQuad === 5) {
            ctxQuadtree.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctxQuadtree.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 250);
            qTree.drawTree(ctxQuadtree);
            drwQuad = 0;
        }
        drwQuad += 1;

        ctxEnt.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEnt.width, canvasEnt.height)

        for(i=0; i<len; i+=1) {
            ent = entityBag[i];

            if(ent.update) {
                ent.update(dTime);
            }

            if(ent.draw) {
                ent.draw(ctxEnt, Camera);
            }
        }

        handleCollisions();

        setTimeout(gameloop, dTime * 1000);
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        addEntity: addEntity,
        removeEntity: removeEntity
    };
}());


var Camera = (function() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;
    var ctx = null;
    var player = null;


    var init = function(_ctx, plyr) {
        ctx = _ctx;
        player = plyr;
        width = ctx.canvas.width;
        height = ctx.canvas.height;
    };

    var update = function() {
        width = ctx.canvas.width;
        height = ctx.canvas.height;

        var plyrAttr = player.getAttr();
        x = (plyrAttr.x - width / 2);
        y = (plyrAttr.y - height / 2);
    };

    var getRelPos = function(entAttr) {

        var relX = entAttr.x - x;
        var relY = entAttr.y - y;

        return {
            x: relX,
            y: relY
        };
    };

    var getPos = function() {
        return {
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
    };

    var getSize = function() {
        return {
            width: width,
            height: height
        };
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        update: update,
        getRelPos: getRelPos,
        getPos: getPos,
        getSize: getSize
    };
}());

var i = 0;
var space = 70;
for(i=0; i<400; i+=1) {
    gameManager.addEntity(new Circle({
        x: 100 + Math.random() * 4850,//(i%20) * space,
        y: 100 + Math.random() * 4850,//Math.floor(i/20)*space,
        color: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'brown', 'violet'][Math.floor(Math.random()*7)],
        droplet: true
    }));
}

gameManager.init('canvas1', 'canvas2', 'canvas3');
```

And last but not least, my css:

```
html, body {
    background: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#viewport {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#viewport canvas {
    position: absolute;
}

canvas {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just hide canvas3 by adding `#canvas3 { display: none; }` rule in your CSS file?

Comment: Well, yeah but i want to make the code more simplified, but your temporary fix works. Thanks for that :)